# $w =\sum_{1\leq i< j\leq 7}z_i z_j =0$ If $z_i$ lies on a unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, algebra-precalculus

Let $z_1, z_2, ......,z_7$ be the vertices of a regular
heptagon that is inscribed in the unit circle with
centre at the origin in the complex plane. Let
$w =\sum_{1\leq i< j\leq 7}z_i z_j$, then |w| is equal to ______

**My Attempt** : If one of the vertex is $(1,0)$ then I am done. $w =\sum_{1\leq i< j\leq 7}z_i z_j  =0$

But if we tilt the polygon in any direction with respect to the origin so that $(1,0)$ does not remain a vertex of the polygon  then what will happen?

Comment: You'd just multiply each $z_i$ by the same unit complex number, so $w$ would still be $0$.

Comment: Hint: $\prod_{i=1}^7 (z-z_i) = z^7 -z_1^7$ and the coefficient of $z^5$ is...

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{1 \le i <j \le 7} z_i z_j= \frac{1}{2} \left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^7 z_k\right )^2-\sum_{k=0}^7  z_k^2\right]$$ Since $z_k$ are the roots of $z^7=1$ so  both $\sum_k z_k$ and $\sum_k z_k^2$ are zero, hemce $w=0$.

Or simply the required expression the value of sum of the par-wise products of rotts $z_k$ of $z^7-1=0$

Comment: You are assuming that one of the $z_i$ is $1$. It is not difficult to deal with this in your proof, but it needs to be done.

Comment: @TonyK, Thank you.